# Creating a scalable XML document with SQL Server FOR XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I want to reproduce this output as an scalable query from the datebase to XML using FOR XML
This is the example of a XML containing an instance Gear of a Claymore, a Bow and a Knight's Armor:

```
<root>
<Gear id='1'>
  <materials>
    <material>
      <id>2</id>
      <material_name> Leather </material_name>
    </material>
    <material>
      <id>1</id>
      <material_name> Bar</material_name>
    </material>
  </materials>

  <category>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Warriors Weapon</name>
  </category>

  <equipment>
    <id> 1</id>
    <equipment_name> Claymore </equipment_name>
    <category> 1</category>
  </equipment>

  <recipes>
    <recipe>
      <equipment_id>1</equipment_id>
      <material_id>1</material_id>
      <material_quantity>12</material_quantity>
    </recipe>
    <recipe>
      <equipment_id> 1 </equipment_id>
      <material_id>2</material_id>
      <material_quantity>20</material_quantity>
    </recipe>
  </recipes>
</Gear>
<Gear id='2'>
    <materials>
      <material>
        <id>3</id>
        <material_name> Plank </material_name>
      </material>
    </materials>

    <category>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Hunter Weapons</name>
    </category>

    <equipment>
      <id> 2</id>
      <equipment_name> Bow </equipment_name>
      <category> 2</category>
    </equipment>

    <recipes>
      <recipe>
        <equipment_id> 2 </equipment_id>
        <material_id>3</material_id>
        <material_quantity>36</material_quantity>
      </recipe>
    </recipes>
  </Gear>
<Gear id='3'>
    <materials>
      <material>
        <id>1</id>
        <material_name> Bar </material_name>
      </material>
    </materials>

    <category>
      <id>4</id>
      <name>Warrior Armour</name>
    </category>

    <equipment>
      <id> 4</id>
      <equipment_name> Knight Amor </equipment_name>
      <category> 4</category>
    </equipment>

    <recipes>
      <recipe>
        <equipment_id> 4 </equipment_id>
        <material_id>1</material_id>
        <material_quantity>16</material_quantity>
      </recipe>
    </recipes>
  </Gear>
</root>
```

This is my actual database:

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Categories];
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Equipment];
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Materials];
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Recipe];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](150) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equipment](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [equipment_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [category_id] [int] NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Materials](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [material_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipe](
    [equipment_id] [int] NULL,
    [material_id] [int] NULL,
    [material_quantity] [int] NULL
);

INSERT [dbo].[Categories] ([id], [name]) VALUES 
(1, N'Warrior Weapons'),
(2, N'Hunter Weapons'),
(3, N'Mage Weapons'),
(4, N'Warrior Armours');

INSERT [dbo].[Equipment] ([id], [equipment_name], [category_id]) VALUES 
(1, N'Claymore', 1),
(2, N'Bow', 2),
(3, N'Fire Staff', 3),
(4, N'Knight Armor', 4);

INSERT [dbo].[Materials] ([id], [material_name]) VALUES 
(1, N'Bar'),
(2, N'Leather'),
(3, N'Plank'),
(4, N'Cloth');

INSERT [dbo].[Recipe] ([equipment_id], [material_id], [material_quantity]) VALUES 
(1, 1, 20),
(1, 2, 12),
(2, 3, 32),
(3, 3, 16),
(3, 1, 8),
(4, 1, 16);
-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

So, as you can see it would be like a Class named Gear, containing an array of Materials, a Category object, an Equipment object and an array of Recipe.

If a new recipe of a Guardian armor is added, i want the query to reproduce it as an instance of Gear with this structure above.

Like this:

```
<root>
[...]
<Gear id='4'>
  <materials>
      <material>
        <id>1</id>
        <material_name> Bar </material_name>
      </material>
    </materials>

    <category>
      <id>4</id>
      <name>Warrior Armour</name>
    </category>

    <equipment>
      <id> 5</id>
      <equipment_name> Guardian Amor </equipment_name>
      <category> 4</category>
    </equipment>

    <recipes>
      <recipe>
        <equipment_id> 5 </equipment_id>
        <material_id>1</material_id>
        <material_quantity>16</material_quantity>
      </recipe>
    </recipes>
  </Gear>
</root>
```

The gear ID is just a reference, so i dont think its important to be attached to a real attribute (like category_id).

Comment: What does "scalable" mean to you in this context and what is it about your solution that does not meet that requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Nested XML fragments relationships with the parent are created via `WHERE ...` clause.

The *dbo.Equipment* table is the top parent. It is used to compose the `<Gear id="N">` XML elements.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Categories;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Equipment;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Materials;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Recipe;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Categories(
    id int NULL,
    name nvarchar(150) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Equipment(
    id int NULL,
    equipment_name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    category_id int NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Materials(
    id int NULL,
    material_name nvarchar(50) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Recipe(
    equipment_id int NULL,
    material_id int NULL,
    material_quantity int NULL
);

INSERT dbo.Categories (id, name) VALUES 
(1, N'Warrior Weapons'),
(2, N'Hunter Weapons'),
(3, N'Mage Weapons'),
(4, N'Warrior Armours');

INSERT dbo.Equipment (id, equipment_name, category_id) VALUES 
(1, N'Claymore', 1),
(2, N'Bow', 2),
(3, N'Fire Staff', 3),
(4, N'Knight Armor', 4);

INSERT dbo.Materials (id, material_name) VALUES 
(1, N'Bar'),
(2, N'Leather'),
(3, N'Plank'),
(4, N'Cloth');

INSERT dbo.Recipe (equipment_id, material_id, material_quantity) VALUES 
(1, 1, 20),
(1, 2, 12),
(2, 3, 32),
(3, 3, 16),
(3, 1, 8),
(4, 1, 16);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT id AS [@id]
, (
    SELECT m.* 
    FROM dbo.Materials AS m 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Recipe AS r ON m.id = r.material_id
    WHERE r.equipment_id = e.id
    FOR XML PATH('material'), TYPE, ROOT('materials')
)
, (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Categories AS c
    WHERE c.id = e.category_id
    FOR XML PATH('category'), TYPE
)
, (
    SELECT id, equipment_name, category_id AS category
    FROM dbo.Equipment AS c
    WHERE c.id = e.id
    FOR XML PATH('equipment'), TYPE
)
, (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Recipe AS r
    WHERE r.equipment_id = e.id
    FOR XML PATH('recipe'), TYPE, ROOT('recipes')
)
FROM dbo.Equipment AS e
FOR XML PATH('Gear'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2adb2960fa4f66d261d64f735060d66d)

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Could simplify by combining the two outer `FOR XML` clauses https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cc65d422ff753a558e180836202e1f6

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. I adjusted the answer.